# Center Align Multiple Spans In One Line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center multiple spans in one line, nut it doesn't work for me. They always center align one beneath each other. I'd really appreciate some help. Here's the code:

```css
 body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        span {
            top: 0;
            transition: 0.1s ease-in;
            position: relative;
        }

        span:hover {
            color: orange;
            top: -10px;
        }
```

```html
  <h1>
        <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: you mean `h1 {text-align:center}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
span {
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    position: relative;
}

span:hover {
    color: orange;
    top: -10px;
}

.centerH1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="centerH1">
   <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
  </h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: COuld you tell me too how to center it vertically now?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `text-align: center;` on the `h1` (i.e. their container) will be sufficient, since `span`s are inline elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  position: relative;
}

span:hover {
  color: orange;
  top: -10px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
</h1>
```

Or do you mean the letters/spans should be below each other and horizontally centered? For this you can use `display: flex` on the `h1`, with the following settings:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  position: relative;
}

span:hover {
  color: orange;
  top: -10px;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
</h1>
```